# Eclipse dialogs open twice when clicked with mouse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, mouse, environment

Within the past 2 weeks, Eclipse has started behaving oddly.  Not sure what changed, although I did install JDK and JRE 7u21.

Any dialog (Search, Eclipse About, Switch workspace, etc.) I open by clicking a menu item with my mouse opens twice.  One dialog displays directly behind another -- when you're done with one and hit Ok or Close, there's another waiting behind it.  If you drag the first one to the side, the other identical dialog is right behind it.

Sometimes the fact that two dialogs open disrupts the contents or functionality of one or both of the dialogs.  For example, the file filters in the search dialog might be blank for one of the two popups, and neither of the two search windows works.

The same dialogs, if opened with keyboard shortcuts (click the Search menu, press F on the keyboard to open the File Search dialog), display only one dialog.  No functionality issues with dialogs opened this way.

No other program exhibits this behavior.

Why is this happening and how do I make it stop?

I've searched google and found no clues.

Here are things I've tried:

- I was using Eclipse 3.8 SR2.  I tried creating a new workspace.  Same behavior in the clean workspace.
- I tried launching Eclipse with the -clean option.  Startup took much longer, but no change in dialog behavior.
- I unzipped an old copy of the Eclipse 3.8 SR2 and tried a clean copy of the Eclipse system.  Same behavior.
- I downloaded and switched to Eclipse 4.2 SR2.  Started a new workspace.  Same behavior.
- I unplugged my USB mouse and tried using the laptop touchpad alone.  Same behavior.
- I've checked workspace\.metadata\.log, but there are no related entries.

Comment: As of today, I've got the same behavior...

Comment: GGTS: Groovy/Grails Tool Suite (Based on eclipse 3.8)

Version: 3.3.0.M1
Build Id: 201304211039

Feels like a late easter nag...

I just remember that yesterday my eclipse did not start up and I used another GGTS install based on eclipse 4.2 to touch the workspace. Afterwards, it worked again with the 3.8 install.
Maybe this is part of the problem.

Comment: Replaced the workspace's .metadata directory with a 10 days old backup. To no avail.

Comment: Just restarted my computer and the behavior is back to normal. Windows 8.

Comment: Restarting does not fix the issue I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just had this problem with my laptop and I found out that it was nview desktop manager. I had turned it on experimenting with different settings. As soon as I disabled the nview, the problem went away within eclipse juno.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Opened nView Desktop Manager, hit Disable.  Problem fixed.  What an obscure issue!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Your welcome. I've noticed other problems with nView before this so that program is at the top of my hit list. This latest problem is putting a nail in the nView coffin unfortunately.

Comment: Perfect answer. I bumped into the same issue and was going nuts for a while.
"Disable nView desktop manager" is what solved my issue immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much for this solution!  Disabling nView Desktop Manager (I'm on version 140.54) instantly fixed this Eclipse problem for me.  I liked the Desktop Manager though because I keep a shortcut in it to lower my screen brightness (because a severely crippled OSD menu on my monitor apparently saved someone money).  **I found that I could keep the Desktop Manager enabled but disable it for Eclipse!**  I added eclipse to the Applications customization screen, then "disabled" that entry and it seems to work fine.  Here were the steps:

Start -> Control Panel -> NVIDIA nView Desktop Manager

if it is disabled, the nView tree control won't open, so click the Enable button to turn on nView Desktop Manager.

1. nView ->
2. Applications (last entry in menu list) ->
3. Add button ->
4. "Find..." button for Application ->
5. drag "Finder Tool" target to Eclipse title bar and release, entry says "eclipse" ->
6. OK button to close Find Application pop-up ->
7. clicked OK button without populating "Class" entry ->
8. select the new "eclipse (Application)" that is now in the listbox ->
9. click Disable button ->
10. unselect main checkbox for "Enable nView Desktop Manager for this application and/or window class" ->
11. click OK ->
12. click Apply button in lower right corner of Desktop Manager window.

I haven't rebooted my system yet to make sure everything will be fine (I prefer to go many days/weeks without rebooting), but I'm assuming it will be.  I decided to post right away in case it would help someone who wanted to keep the nVidia Desktop Manager enabled but couldn't stand the Eclipse double dialog issue.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, you could also see this problem in other systems based on Eclipse (I know I just did).

At work, we use Oracle Application Testing Suite. Its GUI for making scripts (Openscript) is based on Eclipse.

I was having exactly the same problems as the original reporter (right click, bring up properties get two windows one behind the other). It also resulted in duplicate pastes (I'd get the same step pasted in twice). I'd actually reached the point of raising an SR with Oracle.

Disabling NView (in NView Desktop Manager) stopped the problem instantly. Thanks D-Klotz...

Gavin

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for a couple of weeks now after my Eclipse and Java update on my Win7 desktop machine. I realized that I had exactly the same problem in other Java-based applications as well so I was pretty sure it was the Java update. Tried following:

-revert to old version of SDK -> same problem

-uninstall all recent Java updates -> same problem

-different mouse, different driver -> same problem

-windows restore to the point before I went for new SDK -> same problem

Finally I gave up as I was spending more time than re-install...so I re-installed Win 7, installed the latest eclipse (but this time avoided JRE7u21) -> everything works fine!

(note: I had this problem only on my HP desktop (Nvidia NVS 295 graphics card), exactly the same SDK/Java on my laptop works well).

Answer (score 0):

it's in most cases a shortcut from another program that's causing such problems.
in my case i tried everything: deinstalled java, eclipse, cleaned my pc (several dirs and registry): did not help;

nView was the bad program

Answer (score 0):

For me too it was problem with nView, to disable nView for windows, right click on desktop, go to nView Desktop Manager, and click on 'Disable' on the popup. Worked for me.